# Expanding hardware raid array in CentOS

Tags: linux, redhat, centos6, lvm, dell-perc

I added a few drives and expanded my array using Dell's OpenManage utility. I was able to scan the device to show the correct size of /dev/sda. This is on a CentOS 6 system. I went into parted and was prompted to fix the space. Now that is showing up correctly. The one thing I noticed is that the second partition doesn't display a file system type. I don't know how the kickstart does this but my question is, if I add a new partition, I have to provide a file system type to parted. Is this going to throw anything off when I add /dev/sda3 to the existing LVM VolGroup00?

Thanks

```
[root@ dev]# parted /dev/sda
GNU Parted 2.1
Using /dev/sda
Welcome to GNU Parted! Type 'help' to view a list of commands.
(parted) p                                                                
Warning: Not all of the space available to /dev/sda appears to be used, you can fix the GPT to use all of the space (an extra 4686086144 blocks) or continue with the current setting? 
Fix/Ignore? f                                                             
Model: DELL PERC H730P Mini (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 8397GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt

Number  Start   End     Size    File system  Name  Flags

 1      1049kB  269MB   268MB   ext4               boot  <--ext4 for boot -->

 2      269MB   5998GB  5998GB                     lvm <-- no file system -->




[root@ dev]# df -vh
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/VolGroup00-LogVol00
                       20G  6.6G   12G  36% /

tmpfs                  63G  7.8M   63G   1% /dev/shm

/dev/sda1             240M   84M  145M  37% /boot

/dev/mapper/VolGroup00-LogVol04
                       99G  2.8G   91G   3% /opt

/dev/mapper/VolGroup00-LogVol03
                      4.8G   11M  4.6G   1% /tmp

/dev/mapper/VolGroup00-LogVol02
                       10G  736M  8.8G   8% /var

/dev/mapper/VolGroup00-LovVol05
                      5.3T  4.5T  472G  91% /raid01
```

Comment: Are you sure you mean `/dev/sda3`?

Comment: Yeah it's going to be the third partition under /dev/sda. I need to add a new parition. I don't want to run a risk of corrupting the second one by changing the size of it.

Comment: Not like there's really any risk to expanding the existing partition. You're already past the risky parts, i.e. expanding the RAID array.

Comment: But not having a filesystem in parted, isn't that going to be an issue? I never really looked at it before but it just seems odd.